# Data binding with Angular Observables

Tags: angular, observable

Initially, the data is not retrieved from an API call, and so the console throws this:

```
Cannot read property 'whatever' of undefined
```

Which is understandable, and once the data is retrieved, it shows the correct value. What's the best way to get around the console error? There must be something.

In my html, I basically have this:

```
<div>{{data.whatever}}</div>
```

And I'm calling an API through a service like so:

```
this.dataService.getData().subscribe(results => {
    this.data = results;
});
```

Comment: share your code as well.

Comment: Edited to include relevant code.

Comment: for a simple work around, just try `{{data?.whatever}}` but for better solution is to defined, assign and initialize interface.

Comment: Actually, that will work for my purpose. I'm not going to show it anyway if data is undefined. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to check whether the value is undefined or not using [the-safe-navigation-operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-expression-operators#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths)
`{{data?.whatever}}`

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this to **avoid your console error**

```
<div *ngIF="data">{{data.whatever}}</div>
```

And also **call your API service on ngOnInit()** to get a proper results:

```
this.dataService.getData().subscribe(results => {
    this.data = results;
});
```

Comment: I am calling the API service in ngOnInit, but before the promise gets handled, data is still undefined, which is where the error comes from.

Comment: try this in your code to avoid the error <div *ngIF="data">{{data.whatever}}</div>

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understand your question correctly, but if you mean that you want to display something while you are retrieving data from the database, then in your HTML file:

```
<p *ngIf= "this.dbService.isLoading && !this.dbService.error">Loading...</p>
```

In your database service, have properties for isLoading and error so that you can keep track of what state it is in.

```
public whatevers: Whatever[] = [];


public isLoading = true;
  public error = null;


public load() {
this.isLoading = true;
this.fetchWhatever().subscribe( (loadedItems) => {
  this.isLoading = false;
  this.whatevers = loadedItems;
},
(error) => {
  this.error = error.message;
},
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you must call body api

```
    this.dataService.getData().subscribe(results => {
        if(results.status==200)
          {
                 this.data = results.body;
          }
     },
     error=>{
       console.log("Error");
     }
   );
```

and use your html code

```
<div *ngIF="data">{{data.whatever}}</div>
```